# gRPC communication between docker containers

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, grpc, grpc-java

My local (without docker) was fine and worked without any problem.

**LOCAL SETUP** works fine.

**Server-Jar:** running at 8081

**Client-War:** running at 8000 and could make a connection to Server Jar without any problem.

---

**DOCKER SETUP** docker-compose.yml

**Server**

```
employee:
    image: openjdk:jdk-alpine
    container_name: "employee"
    ports:
      - 9081:8080
      - 9991:9990
      - 65193:65193
    volumes:
      - ./Employee/target/Employee-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:/deployments/Employee-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:65193,suspend=n,server=y -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
      - GRPC_PORT=8080
    command: java -jar /deployments/Employee-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar





client:
    image: jboss/wildfly
    container_name: "client"
    ports:
      - 9080:8080
      - 9990:9990
      - 65193:65193
    volumes:
      - ./Service/target/Service.war:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/Service.war
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:65193,suspend=n,server=y -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
      - EMPLOYEE_HOST=localhost:9081
    command: >
      bash -c "/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin Admin#007 --silent && /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0"
links:
  - employee
depends_on:
  - employee
```

**Employee Server Code**

```
Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(Integer.parseInt(env.get("GRPC_PORT")))
        .addService(new Employee())
        .build();
try {
    server.start();
    System.out.println("Server listening at: " + env.get("GRPC_PORT"));
    server.awaitTermination();
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Client Connection Code.**

```
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(env.get("EMPLOYEE_HOST")).usePlaintext().build();
EmployeeServiceGrpc.EmployeeServiceBlockingStub employee = EmployeeServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
```

**Error** Thrown as I make a gRPC call.

> Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN    at
>   deployment.Service.war//io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:235)
>     at
>   deployment.Service.war//io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:216)
>     at
>   deployment.Service.war//io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:141)

Do you think the docker setup is correct? If then I can look for the problem somewhere else

Comment: When running Docker Compose, the `client` service's `localhost` is `client`. So your `client` call to `localhost:9081` refers to the `client` and not to the `server` which you wish. To solve this, you may use `server` in place of `localhost` in the `client` to reference the `server` (host). Similarly, the `client` reference to `0.0.0.0:65193` refers to its port `65193` not the `server` host's. Make sense. To get to `server`, your client should use `server` instead of `localhost` or aliases of localhost.

Comment: You may be familiar with this but, `ports` is used to expose container ports to the host. The `client` configuration `9080:8080` means that you can access this container port **from** the host using `localhost:9080`. Within the Docker Compose network, the container may refer to its own port as `localhost:8080` and other containers in the network may refer to it as `client:8080`. Corrollary, `ports` is used to expose container ports on the host (for debugging commonly and for external access) but need not be used for inter-container comms.

Comment: yes it makes sense, so how the container can access it's host, i've this error `Failed to resolve name. status=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host server,`

Comment: so yes the question is how a container can access its host port? I'm new to docker-compose so I'd appreciate if you can help with code in my docker-compose file

Comment: I think you only need `client` to reference the server using `employee` not `localhost` (and not `0.0.0.0`). And, because you'll then be referencing the container explicitly, you must use the container's ports not the host's ports. On my phone so challenging to type but the client should, e.g. ` EMPLOYEE_HOST=employee:8080`. The `employee` container's `8080` port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this contrived example:

```
version: "3"

services:

  server:
    image: nginx:1.17.3
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx
    expose:
    - "80"
    ports:
    - 8888:80

  client:
    image: busybox:1.31.0
    restart: always
    depends_on:
    - server
    container_name: busybox
    command:
    - ash
    - -c
    - |
      while true;
      do
        wget --spider http://server:80 2>&1
        sleep 5s;
      done;
```

`client` accesses the Nginx container via port `80` but it uses `server` as the host address to resolve to the appropriate (Nginx) container.

If you were to replace `server` with `localhost` in `client`, the client would attempt the `wget` command against itself and this would fail.

Because `server` publishes `8888` to the host, while the Docker Compose is up, from the host (!), you can `wget http://localhost:8888` and this will work (200).

Comment: hey I'm back, it's `:80` that cleared up the confusion. So my understanding is that docker-compose creates a network of machines/instances by the given names, client and server in this example, so the question is can you create more than one network?

Comment: also do I need to have this -> `links:` attribute?

Comment: Using `links` is not necessary in this case because the `services` names (`server`, `client`) suffice. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links